# Css background image not appearing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am working on a webpage for MLA citation. In the top right corner I would like a little box with a gear to configure settings.

Here is the css:

```
#setings{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:#E1E1E1 url('gear.png') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size:45px 45px;
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;  
}
```

And here is the (very simple) html:

```
<div id="setings"></div>
```

The box does appear in the top right corner like I want it to, but the gear [image](http://vector-magz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/gear-vector1.png) doesn't show up. I have already searched stackoverflow and other websites for an answer but I not found anything so far.

Does anyone know what is wrong with me code?

Thank you so much!

Comment: are you sure that your path to image is valid? check if is there any error on consoloe

Comment: @Dvir I am positive, I have selected the correct path and the image does show up under images when I look at the page source. The picture is 600x600 if that helps at all, though I did use the ` background-size:45px 45px;` to correct that.

Comment: 1. can you call the image in a browser using the full URL. 2. Does it work with a simpler CSS declaration (`background-image:url(FULL_URL)`) 3. Is your image with in some parts, making it difficult to see if the correct area is not visible, even if the image is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take "fixed" off of your "background:" line.